# Этимология слова «возбуждение»

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Почему говорят ***возбуждено** уголовное дело*, а не начато, заведено или открыто?
Я имею в виду изначальное: откуда это пошло, почему в законе именно так употреблено слово?

Answer (score 3):

К этимологии Ваш вопрос имеет весьма косвенное отношение. Но вообще-то этимология прозрачна. Слово родственно "будить", "пробуждать" - активизировать, приводить в рабочее состояние. Так что тут употребление представляется вполне естественным.

Что же касается сути вопроса, откуда именно этот термин взялся, - тут интереснее и не все так очевидно. Большинство подобных терминов ведет начало от канцелярского стиля, употребляемого при делопроизводстве начиная, не соврать, века с XVII и по 1917 г. 
Некоторые вещи были слегка поправлены после революции (сыск, например, заменен на розыск), что-то ушло в прошлое, но в основе тот язык, как ни странно, сохранился.
Думаю, что тогда подобные термины выглядели вполне естественными и вопросов "почему так" не возникало.

Comment: То есть дело спало? Как четко слово показывает состояние системы, она спит и на обращения отвечает: чего вы меня будите, когда убьют приходите.

Comment: @Никита не совсем понимаю вопрос... Если вы о том, при чем тут "спать", то действительно почти ни при чем. Значения "буд/буж" (корневого морфа слова "будить" совсем не сводится к "будить ото сна".  Само слово "возбудить" гораздо шире "возбудить интерес", к примеру. Хотя в основе все равно значение "пробуждать".